# An error when running JUnit Test for my web project in Netbeans 8.2 RC said: Need to specify class name in environment or system property

Tags: java, junit, netbeans

When I run my test class, it threw this error:

```
Testcase: testAddSpecialty(web.models.tblSpecialty.SpecialtyDAOTest):   Caused an ERROR
Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:350)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at web.utils.DBHelpers.makeConnection(DBHelpers.java:25)
    at web.models.tblSpecialty.SpecialtyDAO.addSpecialty(SpecialtyDAO.java:143)
    at web.models.tblSpecialty.SpecialtyDAOTest.testAddSpecialty(SpecialtyDAOTest.java:39)
```

This is my test class

```
package web.models.tblSpecialty;

import org.junit.Test; 
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class SpecialtyDAOTest {
    SpecialtyDAO dao = new SpecialtyDAO();
    public SpecialtyDAOTest() {
    } 
@Test
    public void testAddSpecialty() throws Exception {
        String name = "dentistry";
        assertTrue(dao.addSpecialty(name));
    }
```

This is my SpecialtyDAO class to get data from Database

```
public boolean addSpecialty(String specialtyName) throws SQLException, NamingException {
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement stm = null;
        try {
            con = DBHelpers.makeConnection();
            if (con != null) {
                String sql = "INSERT INTO tblSpecialty "
                        + "(SpecialtyName) values(?)";
                stm = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                stm.setString(1, specialtyName);
                int row = stm.executeUpdate();
                if (row > 0) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (stm != null) {
                stm.close();
            }
            if (con != null) {
                con.close();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

my project runs fine on tomcat server, so i don't think it's database connection error. Can anyone help me with this problem?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually you almost gave the answer yourself.

When you execute your the test in NetBeans you're running it outside tomcat (which is a servlet container).

But the code you're trying to test relies on such a servlet container since it retrieves the database connection via `javax.naming` aka `JNDI`. This is just one part of components a servlet container provide to the application running into it.

So if you run your test inside NetBeans that whole environment is not available and so the test is unable to lookup the database connection via `JNDI`.

In order to fix your test you could:

1. Mock out the `DBHelpers.makeConnection()` call to return a database connection of your choice.
2. Initialize `JNDI` manually or with some kind of a framework like [Simple-JNDI](https://github.com/h-thurow/Simple-JNDI).
3. Run your test inside a servlet container.